# Why some character can't be edited in C++?

Tags: c++, string, strcat

I'm trying to write my own `strcat` function in C++, but it has some problems.
My input is two chars `c` and `a`, and my function will return a char pointer to a char which `c` is concatenated with `a`.

For example,
Input: `'abc'` `'xyz'`
Expected Output: `'xyzabc'`
My function's Ouput: `'xyza@▲∩'`

My function returns some special character different to my input.

I debugged my function and found that:

- When `i=0`, `destination[3]` = `source[0]` = `'a'`
- But when `i=1`, `destination[8]` = `source[1]` = `'b'`
- And when `i=2`, `destination[9]` = `source[2]` = `'c'`
- Finally, `destination[10]` = `'\0'`

```c
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

char* mystrcat ( char * destination, const char *source){
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(source); i++) {
        destination[strlen(destination)+i] = source[i];
    }
    destination[strlen(destination)+strlen(source)]='\0';
    return destination;
}

int main() {
    char c[100];
    cin.getline(c, 99);
    char a[100];
    cin.getline(a,99);

    mystrcat(a,c);
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `strlen(destination)` after you've appended the other string to it?

Comment: If you're writing your own strcat function, it should take a parameter `destinationSize` which is the maximum number of chars that can be stored in the destination buffer so that you don't overrun the buffer.  At a glance: if `a` is 99 chars and `c` is 99 chars, what char array has enough space to store the the 198-character result?

Comment: Though the title can be improved.

Comment: @Wyck that would be reimplementing `strncat` rather than `strcat` which will happily overrun a buffer.

Comment: @Chris Fair enough about strcat's happiness  My actual point was to get the asker to think about how they're going to park 2 cars in their 1-car garage, to use an analogy.  If it were declared `char a[200]` I wouldn't have mentioned it because strcat would be guaranteed to have enough room given the other details of the code.  One of three things needs to happen: either use strncat, or make the destination buffer bigger, or limit the sum of the getline chars to be less than the size of the destination buffer (plus a NUL)

Comment: I don't see any dynamic memory allocation which strcat will have. And if you want to implement that in a slightly more modern flavor let your string cat function at least return a std::unique_ptr (in current C++ the use of raw pointers is no longer recommended).

Comment: @PepijnKramer where does `strcat` do dynamic memory allocation? And if we're taking about actually using C++ we'd be using `std::string` rather than any of this C string stuff  in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

`strlen` returns the length from the pointer to the first `\0` it encounters. Here, during the loop, you overwrite this character in the `destination` pointer, so subsequent calls to `strlen` will return the length to some random point in memory that happens to hold this character.

One easy fix is to extract the `strlen` results before you start modifying strings:

```cpp
char* mystrcat (char *destination, const char *source) {
    int destLen = strlen(destination);
    int srcLen = strlen(source);
    for (int i = 0; i < srcLen; i++) {
        destination[destLen + i] = source[i];
    }
    destination[destLen + srcLen] = '\0';
    return destination;
}
```

Comment: Since `destination` ceases to be a valid null-terminated string after the very first iteration, `strlen(destination)` in subsequent iterations exhibit [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984).

Comment: @Chris But where do you see `strlen(destination)` in the loop.

Comment: A simpler implementation would not need to use `strlen` at all. Simply advance `destination` until you reach its `'\0'`, then copy from `source` until you reach its '\0'`

Comment: @CGi03 Chris was clearly referring to the OP's code, not this answer's code. The comment should have been posted on the question, not on this answer

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Meant as a suggestion to include the words undefined behavior in your answer. Your answer was good enough that I abandoned my own. Congrats on beating me to it!

Comment: @Chris you make a good point. The importance of "undefined behavior" is that it allows more latitude than just returning a random length.  If you're lucky, it could crash the program.  If you're unlucky you could find [demons flying from your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Answer (score -1):

Given below is the correct implementation of the code.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void mystrcat ( char* destination, const char *source){
    int p;
    for(p=0; destination[p] != '\0'; p++);//pointing to the index of the last 
    character of x

    for(int q=0; source[q] != '\0'; q++,p++)
    {
    destination[p]=source[q];
    }
    destination[p]='\0';
    }
int main() {
   char c[100];
   cin.getline(c, 99);
   char a[100];
   cin.getline(a,99);
   mystrcat(a,c);
   cout<<a;
   return 0;
 }
```

As the length of source will get updated in your code, it gives special symbols as output.

Comment: The "special symbols" are a direct consequence of undefined behavior.  They certainly aren't guaranteed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h , and you should explain what changes you made to the code and *why*.